# my sql access denied in spite of granting privileges

Tags: mysql, database, web

I wanted to execute instructions to create and manipulate a data base so first I created a user as follow:

```
shell>cd program\xampp\mysql\bin;
shell>mysql -u root -h localhost
mariadb[(none)]>create user 'iw3htp@localhost'identified by 'sth';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'iw3htp@localhost';
flush privileges;
```

but when I want to execute instructions for creating and manipulating a database using source file or manually i face with error 1044 that says me "Access denied for user 'iw3htp'@'localhost'for database foo.

so whats wrong with this?
what I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user access is defined by the user name and the host. Two parts.

With this:

```
create user 'iw3htp@localhost' ...
```

as a single string you have created a user

```
'iw3htp@localhost'@localhost
```

Change it to

```
create user 'iw3htp'@'localhost' identified by 'sth';
```

and

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'iw3htp'@'localhost';
```